# tcpdump of udp packets containing data

Tags: linux, udp, tcpdump

Running linux ubuntu.

Essentially, why is this command a syntax error: -

```
tcpdump -i eth0 -n udp -X -v -s 1514 'tcp[40:4] = 0x31323334'
```

Which should show udp packets with '1234' at the 40th byte.

I mean, I get that udp isn't a tcp packet, but the logic should still work. Given it doesn't how can I write this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try the following:

```
tcpdump -i eth0 -X -v -s 1514 'udp[40:4] = 0x31323334'
```

Afaik, proto relop filters should match only the protocol you specify, -n udp should not be needed.

Answer (score 1):

tcpdump is confused what to take as filtering parameter. When you've explicitly used udp, then it captures all the udp packets or if you want particular udp packet then you can specify the offset. So, based on what you need either specify udp with offset or simply udp if you want to capture all the udp packets. Something like below should meet your requirement:

```
        tcpdump -i eth0 -n -X -v -s 1514 'udp[40:4] = 0x31323334'
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer.  I ticked the first correct solution, which I hope is correct manners.  I'm still working on the offset, apparently my byte string is at [20] not [40] so I guess the udp array skips the header.  Also, I did try udp[] but as I found no reference to that I just figured it didn't exist!  It's now working for me, thanks again.

Comment: No problem. Yes, I've also noticed that your udp offset isn't correct, it's not going to capture udp packets with 1234.

Comment: The UDP payload seems to start at udp[8:x] in `tcpdump`'s arithmetic. I guess `tcpdump` counts offset from the start of the UDP header (which makes sense), not from the start of IP packet. So to look into UDP data/payload, can do either `udp[8:4]` which is at same offset as `ip[28:4]` except latter likely ignores protocol while former I expect matches the UDP protocol.